# R: How to filter/smooth binary signal

Tags: r

I have a binary vector which represents a time series. I'd like to filter out fast switches like 00000001100000000 should be zeros and likewise 11111111111011111 should be just ones.

What kind of filter/function would be appropriate for that  task?

Comment: how exactly do you define a 'fast switch'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is a stupid approach but `rle`/`inverse.rle` seem to be good candidates. E.g. if you define a *fast switch* as a period of less than 3 equal values:

```
b1 <- c(rep(0, 7), rep(1, 2), rep(0, 7))
b2 <- c(rep(1, 10), 0, rep(1, 4))

binaryFilter <- function(x, threshold=3) {
  r <- rle(x)
  isBelowThreshold <- r$lengths < threshold
  r$values[isBelowThreshold] <- abs(1-r$values[isBelowThreshold])
  return(inverse.rle(r))
}

binaryFilter(b1)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

binaryFilter(b2)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about taking the neighbouring values into account using a weighted average? In this case the 2 neighbours of every value (which has 2 neighbours on both sides) are considered. Of course this can be adjusted.

```
> v <- sample(c(0,1),30,replace=TRUE)

> v
 [1] 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0

# embed(v,5) is a short version for this:
# cbind(v[1:26],v[2:27],v[3:28],v[4:29],v[5:30])

> m <- embed(v,5)

> c(round(m %*% c(.1,.2,.4,.2,.1)))
 [1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

---

```
before: 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
after:  . . 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 . .
```

as you can see, the loners are gone.

---

As suggested by sgibb, the whole fuzz can be boiled down to:

```
round(filter(v, c(.1,.2,.4,.2,.1)))
```

(But I guess the above written out version makes it clear what is done, which is why I leave it)

Comment: Instead of your `cbind` call you could/should use `embed`.

Comment: I guess it is exactly the same like `round(filter(v, c(.1,.2,.4,.2,.1)))`.

Comment: oh damn it - and I thought I invented this algorithm ... :/ ... just kidding. thanks again! that is much nicer

Answer (score 1):

Another solution similar to  @sgibb solution but using `rollapply` from `zoo` package.

1. Find the trend of the sequence( preponderant value)
2. roll apply in a fixed window width along the series and take trend if is exists with the window.

Simpler to explain by code :)

```
filter_bin <-
function(vec,width =3){
  trend <- 
    as.numeric(names(which.max(table(vec))))
  rollapply(vec,width,function(x) 
  if(trend %in% x) trend else unique(x))
}

  filter_bin(b2)
  ## 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  filter_bin(b1)
  ## 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```